# Regex replace html and add spacing on div

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello I would like help creating a regex that replaces all html tags but when there is an end div and start div next to each other it adds a space, so for example

`This <b>is</b> <div>a</div><div>test</div>`

`This is a test`

What I currently have for regex is /(<([^>]+)>)/ig which will replace all html tags but Im wondering how do I also add a space whenever there is a closing div and starting div next to each other.

I tried using /(<([^>]+)>)/ig to replace the html which works but I need help with the spacing on divs when they are next to each other

Comment: see: [Why it's not possible to use regex to parse HTML/XML: a formal explanation in layman's terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7387397

Comment: What about replacing `(?: *<[^>]+>)+` with a space

Comment: @pilchard Do you happen to know how to parse HTML tags with a parser ? Most parsers use regex for this.

Answer (score 1):

JS has built-in support for HTML parsing. Use that instead:

```js
function getSpaceSeparatedText(html) {
  // Create an element and use it as a parser
  let parser = document.createElement('div');
  
  parser.innerHTML = html;
  
  const result = [];
  
  for (const node of parser.childNodes) {
    // Get the trimmed text
    const text = node.textContent.trim();
    
    // If text is not empty, add it to result
    if (text) {
      result.push(text);
    }
  }
  
  return result.join(' ');
}
```

Try it:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

function getSpaceSeparatedText(html) {
  let parser = document.createElement('div');
  
  parser.innerHTML = html;
  
  const result = [];
  
  for (const node of parser.childNodes) {
    const text = node.textContent.trim();
    
    if (text) {
      result.push(text);
    }
  }
  
  return result.join(' ');
}

const html = `
This <b>is</b> 
<div>a</div><div>test</div>
`;

console.log(getSpaceSeparatedText(html));
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

***Update**: Adding a new group to the top caused an offset by one to the subsequent backreferences.*
*Was fixed.*

This removes all HTML tags and invisible content (https://regex101.com/r/2ACiDg/1),
but you need a callback to insert a space between a closing and open div.

```js
var text = "This <b>is</b> <div>a</div><div>test</div>"
text = text.replace(/(<\/div\s*><div\s*>)|<(?:(?:(?:(script|style|object|embed|applet|noframes|noscript|noembed)(?:\s+(?=((?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|(?:(?!\/>)[^>])?)+))\3)?\s*>)[\S\s]*?<\/\2\s*(?=>))|(?:\/?[\w:]+\s*\/?)|(?:[\w:]+\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]?)+\s*\/?)|\?[\S\s]*?\?|(?:!(?:(?:DOCTYPE[\S\s]*?)|(?:\[CDATA\[[\S\s]*?\]\])|(?:--[\S\s]*?--)|(?:ATTLIST[\S\s]*?)|(?:ENTITY[\S\s]*?)|(?:ELEMENT[\S\s]*?))))>/g, function(match, grp1)
    {
       if ( grp1 > "" ) 
          return " "; 
       else
          return ""
    }
);

console.log( text );
```